# Struts2 fileUpload and validation interceptors

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, nullpointerexception, interceptor

I'm trying to put constraints on uploaded files to my website using the `fileUpload` interceptor. Upon failing validation, I receive a null pointer exception later on in my `validate()` method. I currently have my interceptors in my `struts.xml` like this:

```
<interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="maximumSize">1048576</param>
</interceptor-ref> 
<interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
<interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
```

I have figured out that the reason for this might have something to do with `fileUpload` coming before validation. I know it needs to happen in this order, but if the `fileUpload` fails, then I am not getting the other inputted data from my form; the fields are all null.

I am trying to, upon failing validation, take the user back to the form with the rest of their inputted data already populated back into the form after a failed validation. How would I go about making the request continue instead of stopping once it fails the upload?

Exception:

```
Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
File:   profiles/actions/UpdateProfileAction.java
Line number:    183
Stacktraces

java.lang.NullPointerException
profiles.actions.UpdateProfileAction.validate(UpdateProfileAction.java:183)
   com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doBeforeInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:251)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
etc.
```

which points us to the action validation method:

```
profile.setAvailabilityLength(Jsoup.clean(availabilityLength.trim(), Whitelist.basic()));
```

where we are not checking to see if `availabilityLength == null`. Checking would solve the issue, but the form would be repopulated with null data instead of what the user entered.

Comment: What about the results, how have you configured them ? Stack trace of exception please and some action and struts.xml code also is required to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I added the things you asked for to my post.

Comment: I didn't find any struts.xml code neither the actions code, only the exception trace. 
`java.lang.NullPointerException
profiles.actions.UpdateProfileAction.validate(UpdateProfileAction.java:183)` - it clearly explains the location of the error. Further I can help only if code is shown.